# How to display the application version and Grails version in Grails 3?

Tags: grails

I have a simple controller in `Grails 3` that displays both the application version and `Grails` version on a web page. I am not getting an error but the version number displayed is not correct either.

http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#versioning

Above is the official documentation link from where I took this sample out, modified it a bit and tested it out.

**VersionDisplayController.groovy**

```
import grails.util.GrailsUtil

class VersionDisplayController {

    def index() {
        def appVersion = grailsApplication.metadata.getApplicationVersion()

        def grailsVersion = grailsApplication.metadata.getGrailsVersion()
        def grailsVersionThruGrailsUtil = GrailsUtil.grailsVersion

        def message = "Application Version: ${appVersion}, Grails Version: ${grailsVersion}, Grails Version Thru GrailsUtils: ${grailsVersionThruGrailsUtil}"
        render message
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Application Version: @info.app.version@, 
Grails Version: @info.app.grailsVersion@, 
Grails Version Thru GrailsUtils: 3.3.2
```

**application.yml**

```
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: evn.var.reader.demo
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
    gorm:
        reactor:
            # Whether to translate GORM events into Reactor events
            # Disabled by default for performance reasons
            events: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
```

Comment: Is `grailsVersion` property set to a different grails version in `gradle.properties` file?

Comment: Isn't that supposed to work, but only if you run the uberjar?  E.g. it won't work while you run that direclty (aka `bootRun`)?